# Use Perl to search for a match between two files

Tags: regex, string, perl, file, list

I have two files: `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. Both contains lines in this format:

**file1**

```
name1:value1
```

**file2**

```
name2:value2
```

I want to check if `value1` is found in `list2` (in the `name2` string)

I have this function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

sub loadf($);

print "Starting main program\n";
my @list1 = loadf("list1.txt");
my @list2 = loadf("list2.txt");

my $workernum = 10; 
open(OK, '>>', 'valid.txt');
open(ER, '>>', 'invalid.txt');
$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($workernum);

my $cnt = 0;
foreach $line (@list1) {
    $cnt++;
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
    my @data1 = split(":", $line);
    my $name1 = $data1[0];
    my $value1 = $data1[1];
    my @data2 = split(":", $list2);
    my $name2 = $data2[0];
    my $value2 = $data2[1];

    if (/$value1/i ~~ @list2) 
    {
        print OK $name1 . " - " . $value2 . "\n";
        print " [+] Found: " . $name1 . " - " . $value2 . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print ER $name1 . "\n";
        print " [x] Unknown: " . $name1 . " - " . $value1 . "\n";
    }
    $pm->finish;
}

close(OK);
close(ER);
print "\n*** Finished ***\n";

sub loadf($) {
    my @file;
    open(FILE, $_[0] . "\n") or die("[+] Couldn't open " . $_[0] . "\n");
    @file = <FILE>;
    close(FILE);
    return @file;
}

__END__
```

which is not working. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I wanted to process it using multi threads, tried and didn't work, so parallel fork won cause it worked. but that's not important ...

Comment: Try removing the `"\n"` from your `open` in `sub loadf`. It doesn't work for me when I try to open a file that has a newline character in its name.

Comment: lol. although I'm a n00b in perl coding this comment is so funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(F,'list1.txt');
my @list1=<F>;
close(F);
open(F,'list2.txt');
my @list2=<F>;
close(F);
chomp(@list1,@list2);
foreach my $line (@list1)
{
    if ($line=~/.+\:.+/)
    {
        my @data1 = split(":", $line);
        if (my @d2=grep /$data1[1]\:/i,@list2){print " [+] Found: " . $data1[0] . " - " . [split(':',$d2[0])]->[1] . "\n";   }
        else { print " [x] Unknown: " . $data1[0] . " - " . $data1[1] . "\n"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 21. this is the line: if (grep /\:$data1[1]/,@list2){ print " [+] Found: " . $data1[0] . " - " . $data1[1] . "\n"; }

Comment: and the format I need if found is: name1:value2. I mean if name2 is found in value1 to print to screen / file the following line: name1:value2

Comment: tested and nothing shows. no found or no unknown print. probably it is not found in condition: if ($line=~/.+\:.+/)

Comment: it's working now. there were some spaces and the files wasn't converted to unix. thank you

Comment: there is only one problem. I have in some strings the following char & and in that case shows unknown although it is ok

Answer (score 1):

Erm... I really don't get your algorithm, sorry. First you read all the lines from compared files into two arrays, then you forking the processor loop but, as I see it, make no attempts to split these workers' job into chunks (to parallel it).

I'd suggest trying a bit different approach: slurp only the second file, then process the first file line by line. You didn't mention whether names and values of the second file are unique; I suppose they're not, but the program could be made even simpler if they are.

```
open my $caf, '<', 'list2.txt' or die $!, "\n";
my $checkedAgainst = do { local $/;  <$caf>; };

open my $cf, '<', 'list1.txt' or die $!, "\n";

my $workernum = 10; 
$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($workernum);

while (<$cf>) {
  my $pid = $pm->start and next;
  my ($nameToCheck, $valueToCheck) = split /:/;
  if ($checkedAgainst =~ /^\Q$valueToCheck\E:(.+)$/m) {
    print " [+] Found: $nameToCheck - $1", "\n";
  }
  else {
    print " [x] Unknown: $nameToCheck - $valueToCheck", "\n";
  }
}
$pm->finish;
```

In other words, I first load the second file into one big string, then try to match it with the lines from the first file (line by line). I don't know, what symbols could appear in your values, that's why \Q-\E (quotemeta operators) are used there.

**UPDATE:** attempted to make this code fork, have no means to test it where I stand though.

Comment: name1, name2 and value2 are unique. only value1 from the first file is not unique. I wanna use forks because I wanna process the files faster. file1 is around 20Mb and file2 has around 1000 records

Comment: and your answer can be very good but I don't know how to modify my script according to your answer, I mean adding your piece of code inside my fork function, because I don't understand it. too advanced for me

Comment: I'm sorry again, but why you intend to use a fork here in the first place?

Comment: because I have a lot of files to process this way and cannot wait until they are processed line by line with only one thread/fork

Comment: A lot of list1 files, list2 files or both? If the latter, you may get better results (which will be faster to implement, btw) with just shell-scripting the calling of several perl scripts with two arguments - file1name and file2name...

Comment: the list2 file is only around 1000 lines long. I have a lot of file1 type files to check